# Creating an ansible-playbook to install any version of a package

Tags: ansible, system-administration

I am creating an ansible-playbook that installs elasticsearch package. My playbook works fine for any one version of the elasticsearch. What I want to do is create an ansible-playbook that installs any version that the user specifies. Basically I want to give user the choice to choose any version he wants.

The playbook-below install only version 7.x.x

```
- name: installing elastic
  hosts: <myhost>
  tasks:
    - name: Import the Elasticsearch PGP Key
      shell: |
        wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
      args:
        warn: no

    - name: Add repository
      copy:
        dest: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
        content: |
          deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
    - name: Install the Elasticsearch package
      apt:
        name: elasticsearch
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
```

I tried adding a variable file that has versions and replacing that specific version in playbook with variable names as shown below. (It doesnt work though)

```
- name: installing elastic
  hosts: <myhost>
  vars_files: 
    -  version_var.yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Import the Elasticsearch PGP Key
      shell: |
        wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
      args:
        warn: no

    - name: Add repository
      copy:
        dest: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-{{version_7}}.list
        content: |
          deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/{{version_7}}/apt stable main
    - name: Install the Elasticsearch package
      apt:
        name: elasticsearch
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
```

Contents of version_var.yaml file

```
version_6: 6.x
version_7: 7.x
```

I believe there is some sensible way to do this, maybe use conditions. Anyone who can point me to right direction?

Comment: `(It doesnt work though)` [does not accurately describe the problem you're facing](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please see [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and pay attention to the section about [Creating a minimal complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you share error output or what exactly doesn't work through.
I've tested your playbook and it worked correctly using `ansible [core 2.13.1]`.

```yaml
.
├── elastic.yml
└── version_var.yaml
```

elastic.yml

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files: 
    - version_var.yaml
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ version_7 }}"
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "7.x"
}
```

**Anyway, there is a better way to get the major version number:**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    elastic_version: 7.16.2
    elastic_major_version: "{{ elastic_version.split('.')[0] }}.x"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ elastic_major_version }}"
```

The output:

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "7.x"
}
```

**Always consider using modules instead of shell commands:**

```yaml
- hosts: myhosts
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    elastic_version: 7.16.2
    elastic_major_version: "{{ elastic_version.split('.')[0] }}.x"
  tasks:
  - name: Import the Elasticsearch PGP Key
    apt_key:
      url: "https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch"
      state: present

  - name: Add repository
    apt_repository:
      repo: "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/{{ elastic_major_version }}/apt stable main"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes

  - name: Install the Elasticsearch package
    apt:
      name: elasticsearch
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
```

Comment: Awesome @Khaled... This is exactly what I was looking for. There was nothing wrong in my initial code just that I thought there might be a better way of doing things. If u could explain me `{{ elastic_version.split('.')[0] }}.x` this line.

Comment: It splitts the string 7.16.2 based on the dot into array [7,16,2]. The [0] refers to the first element in the array, then the .x is added to the splitt result.

Comment: I tried the above code in a completely new host and it gives error `fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "apt cache update failed"}` any idea??

Comment: Add `update_cache: yes` to the Add repository task, or manually do  `apt update` on the host